# create bootstrap datepicker object before conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery-1.12.4.js and
Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.7.1 (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)

Loading both file dynamically from js

I am creating bootstrapDP object for use and keep both object

```
if (!$.fn.bootstrapDP && $.fn.datepicker && $.fn.datepicker.noConflict) {
     var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
     $.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;
 } else {
     console.log(" ELSE ");
 }
```

Using object as

```
$('.datepickerClass').bootstrapDP({console.log('My code here')});
```

Problem:
When else part execute how I can set bootstrapDP object of datepicker.

Please also suggest if else part execute wrongly.

Comment: What is the issue preventing you from setting the object?

Comment: When else part execute $.fn.bootstrapDP object not create so datepicker not work.